# Json not recognised in vs2019

Tags: json, visual-studio

In VS2013 I have json 12.1 installed and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` works perfectly.
I'm trying out the free version of vs2019 and installed json v9.0. This is all that is available. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` doesn't work, the using directive is greyed out. It is showing in the references. I tried to get v12.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not resolve the using directive, so I had to reference it directly,  `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and all worked. Should have tried that first.